# JSON.NET Property as Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization, json.net

I have a C# class like this

```
public class Person
{
  string firstname {get; set;}
  string lastname {get; set;}
  string onRenderFunction {get; set;}
}
```

Then I setup the class like this:

```
var superman = new Person
{ 
    firstname = "Clark",
    lastname = "Kent",
    onRenderFunction = "renderPersonComplete"
}
```

What I want is the "onRenderFunction" to be serialized to a method - not a string. Like this;

```
{ 
  "firstname": "Clark",
  "lastname": "Kent",
  "onRenderFunction": renderPersonComplete
}
```

So when the serialized object is returned via an Ajax call and given to a plugin which has the ability to call a function "onRenderFunction", the plugin would see the function is set and call a function setup like this:

```
var renderPersonComplete = function() {
   alert('do something on render complete');
};
```

How would I setup JSON.NET to serialize the Person class to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "onRenderFunction" to be serialized to a method"? Do you want to assign a JavaScript function to a string property in C#?

Comment: Added more detail to the function. I am passing the serialized object as a Javascript object via an Ajax call to a jQuery plugin. The plugin sees if the onRenderFunction property on the javascript object is a function and if so calls it.

Comment: Why not just add the function to the JS object after you get the data from ajax?

Comment: The object to be serialized is setup server side and the callback changes with business logic. I need the ability to setup the entire object given to the plugin.

Comment: The way to do it is to use javascript eval. It  an be done this way eval(yourjsonobject.onRenderFunction)

Comment: `eval` is quite dangerous with JSON responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some additional processing to assign the function to the property because JSON by definition is just key-value pairs of primitives, it does not know functions.

So initially your data from ajax will look like:

```
var data = { 
  "firstname": "Clark",
  "lastname": "Kent",
  "onRenderFunction": "renderPersonComplete"
}
```

Let's say you have a function called `renderPersonComplete` in `window`'s scope:

```
window.renderPersonComplete = function() {
   alert('do something on render complete');
};
```

Now you have to modify your data to assign the function:

```
data.onRenderFunction = window[data.onRenderFunction] // This assigns the function to onRenderFunction  property.
```

The name of the function is decided in the server side based on your logic.